# Handling the Income from an Income-Only Medicaid Asset Protection Trust

Tags: united-states, trusts, illinois

My family has created an Income-Only Medicaid Asset Protection Trust for my mother.  I have some questions about how the interest (income) part of this works logistically.

I am the Trustee, and have created the bank accounts for the money with a bank that supports trusts, which is also a bank where I have my own accounts.  When I login to their website, I can see both my own accounts and the trust accounts.  My mother's tax information was provided when setting up the account, as the interest income goes to her and she will get the 1099 for it.

One more bit of background: our attorney who set up the trust said that we need to be careful to only add assets to the account *once*, as the Medicaid lookback period is tied to the last date of assets being added.  I believe my attorney on this fact, but have been unable to find a good resource that explains this.

Per the bank, I can choose to have the income transferred directly into my personal account, or they can send me a check.  There is no option for having the income sent directly to my mother or transferred into her personal account.

I want to make sure I am doing this right, and have a few concerns.  I want to make sure I don't do something odd now that will come back to bite us for Medicaid eligibility ten years from now.  So I guess my main questions surround how the program tracks this information--I want to understand better so I can avoid making a costly mistake.

If I accidentally (or purposely) leave some of the interest income in the trust, does that count as adding an asset and thus reset the lookback?

Does the interest going from the trust => me => my mother look odd from an accounting/tax perspective?

Is there some government agency that *cares* how the interest gets disbursed, or do the numbers just have to add up after the fact (e.g. when they look at her Medicaid eligibility down the road)?

Comment: Does this attorney specialize in Medicaid issues? If yes, they should tell you the rules, follow them exactly. If they don't specialize in Medicaid issues, I would be worried. I am not a lawyer, here is my understanding. To go on Medicaid, you must have almost no assets, and you must not have given away any assets during the lookback period. By transferring assets to a trust, you are claiming that the assets don't belong to your mother anymore.

Comment: ... When you apply for Medicaid someday, the government won't necessarily investigate, you will certify that those are the facts, and if you lie, that is fraud, a crime.